# Is there a reason to put a product in both the Child and Parent Categories?

Tags: categories, woocommerce-offtopic

I have a few product Parent Categories with Child Categories.

Is there a difference if I place the products in both the Child and Parent Categories, or if I just place it in the Child Category? In the latter case, if I click on the parent archive page, the product will still show up...

Any reason why I should do one over the other?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Most of my Woocommerce clients only have the child category checked, not the parent.

For instance, this structure is the most widely used when you have subcategories:

```
[ ] Clothing
    [ ] Pants
    [ ] Shirts
[ ] Music
    [X] Rock
    [ ] Classical
```

The single product page would show this for the product categories:

```
Categories: Rock
```

But if you chose to check both the parent and child category, like this:

```
[ ] Clothing
    [ ] Pants
    [X] Shirts
[X] Music
    [X] Rock
    [ ] Classical
```

The single product page would show this for the product categories:

```
Categories: Music, Rock
```

But as per usual, it depends on your theme and any plugins that may deal with category archives. The main thing to remember is that when you browse category archives, all child categories are shown.

Answer (score 0):

Might be a theme concern,

In my theme, if I do not add to parent it does not show. It gives more option to display the best of your products in the parent as opposed to all of them.